# Create a pipeline on azure devops to deploy a docker container on azure app service?

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops, azure-container-registry, azure-webapps

I have a docker image in my Azure Container Registry and a Web App For Containers(Linux). Now, I want to create a release pipeline which should be able to deploy that container for Azure Container Registry to Web App For Container. I know I can do this manually but I need to Automate this process through Azure DevOps.

Comment: I would suggest you start with the devops pipeline documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/?view=azdevops Stack Overflow is a developer site so without any error messages or code samples to help you debug it is hard to give you a definitive answer

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to make a release pipeline to deploy docker image on Azure web app for container and I made that pipeline by following this tutorial.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/cd/deploy-docker-webapp?view=azdevops&viewFallbackFrom=vsts

I hope this can help others as well. Thank you